# How can I strip block comments with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, stripping

I am working on a preprocessor that is analyzing a DSL. My goal is to remove the comments.
The block comment facility is demarcated by `%%` before and after. I do not have to worry about %% being in strings, by the definition of the language.

I am using this `s///` regex. Unfortunately, it seems to match everything and wipe it out:

```
#Remove multiline comments.
$text_string =~ s/%%.*%%//msg;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the first thing you can do is make it non-greedy:

```
.*?
```

otherwise,

> %%  some text %%
>
> real content
>
> %% other text %%

will all be wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

From [perlfaq6: What does it mean that regexes are greedy? How can I get around it?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#Can_I_use_Perl_regul)

---

Most people mean that greedy regexes match as much as they can. Technically speaking, it's actually the quantifiers (?, *, +, {}) that are greedy rather than the whole pattern; Perl prefers local greed and immediate gratification to overall greed. To get non-greedy versions of the same quantifiers, use (??, *?, +?, {}?).

An example:

```
$s1 = $s2 = "I am very very cold";
$s1 =~ s/ve.*y //;      # I am cold
$s2 =~ s/ve.*?y //;     # I am very cold
```

Notice how the second substitution stopped matching as soon as it encountered "y ". The *? quantifier effectively tells the regular expression engine to find a match as quickly as possible and pass control on to whatever is next in line, like you would if you were playing hot potato.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have read entire code into the variable $str and between %% and %% there is no possibility of a single % occuring, you could use this.

$str =~ s/%%([^%]+)%%//g;